# Unable to format RegEx to handle Dollar Sign ($)

Tags: regex

I am stuck trying to figure out how to get a RegEx text search to work with a dollar sign. Let's say I have two strings:

TestPerson One | 123456789 | ($100.00) | $0 | 03/27/2018 | Open

TestPerson Two | 987654321 | ($250.00) | ($25) | 03/27/2018 | Open

Using jQuery, I am creating the RegEx. If I was to search for TestPerson, the RegEx would look like this:

```
/^(?=.*\bTestPerson).*$/i
```

This would return both strings, as they both contain TestPerson. If I try and search for $, I get zero results even though both strings contian a $. I know the dollar sign is a special character in RegEx, but escaping it does not work either.

How can I format my RegEx to where searching for $ will return both results?

Thanks!

Comment: Just escape it `\$`

Comment: As per the post, escaping it does not work.

Comment: Then the question isn't clear. What is the end result the OP is looking to obtain?

Comment: If I enter $ into my search, I want to see both of the example rows returned as having a match.If I enter TestPerson, I want to see both rows returned as having a match.

Comment: @CameronGray just use `str.includes()` as such: `str.includes('TestPerson')` and `str.includes('$')`. No need for regex.

Answer (score 0):

I think this seems multiline modifier on-off problem. I guess you turned off the multiline modifier and implemented the regex so the unexpected output results.  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/28)

If you turned on the multiline modifier, you could get the output you want. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/27)

Answer (score -1):

To check whether or not a string contains a substring, you don't regex: JavaScript has the string method [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). This method searches a string for a given value and returns `true` if it exists in the string and `false` otherwise.

```js
var a = [
  'TestPerson One | 123456789 | ($100.00) | $0 | 03/27/2018 | Open',
  'TestPerson Two | 987654321 | ($250.00) | ($25) | 03/27/2018 | Open'
]

a.forEach(function(s) {
  console.log(s.includes('TestPerson') && s.includes('$'))
})
```